# using bash, create files based on pattern match

Tags: command-line, text-processing

we have a file with content as below.

```
/* ----------------- pattern_1 ----------------- */ 

jb: pattern_1   Data: asdflj  adfas Log: dir/log1

/* ----------------- pattern_2 ----------------- */ 

jb: pattern_2   typ: CM comm: ${dir}/DISPV mach: au_buh description: "run flag"


/* ----------------- pattern_3 ----------------- */ 

jb: pattern_3   typ: fw  own: buh out_file: "${log}/jl.log" err: "log.err"
```

the file has to be split into 3 and created as 3 seprate files as below:

**pattern_1.txt**

```
/* ----------------- pattern_1 ----------------- */ 

jb: pattern_1   Data: asdflj  adfas Log: dir/log1
```

**pattern_2.txt**

```
* ----------------- pattern_2 ----------------- */ 

jb: pattern_2   typ: CM comm: ${dir}/DISPV mach: au_buh description: "run flag"
```

**pattern_3.txt**

```
/* ----------------- pattern_3 ----------------- */ 

jb: pattern_3   typ: fw  own: buh out_file: "${log}/jl.log" err: "log.err"
```

tried "awk pattern matching", didn't work out. any help ??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77885761/1030675

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's another awk approach:

```
awk '/----/{ f=$3 }; { print > f }' file
```

The script will check if the current line matches `---` and, if it does, it saves the third field of that line as the variable `f`. Awk splits each input line into fields on whitespace (by default), so if the line looks like

```
/* ----------------- pattern_2 ----------------- */
```

Then, the first field is `/*`, the second is `-----------------` and the third is `pattern_2`.

Next, the script prints into a file whose name is whatever is stored in the `f` variable (`print > f`). The result of all this is three files named `pattern_1`, `pattern_2` and `pattern_3`, each with the relevant contents.

If you really want to have them have extensions (this is not needed and not helpful in Linux, it's only for you to know the file type; personally I never uses such things since they just clutter up my files). you can just change the last `print` to `{ print > f".txt" }`.

Comment: If you change `print > f".txt"` to `print > (f".txt")` it'll work in more awks, and if you add a `close()` it'll work for larger input files too.

Comment: Hi @terdon , thanks for the reply and explanation.

But what if there are no spaces in the line (/* -----------------pattern_2----------------- */). in such case, how can we take string ??

Comment: @team9 That would be something like `gawk 'match($0, /----([^-]+)/, m){ f=m[1] } { print > (f".txt") }' file` but, `match()` is a GNU AWK's function and would require that to work AFAIK ... However if one of the other (none pattern) lines happened to contain `----word` for example then that will fail.

Comment: @team9 if the example in your question doesn't cover all your requirements then fix the example in your question, don't add requirements in comments where they can't be formatted and could be missed.

Comment: @terdon FWIW I frequently use extensions as, for example, I may have one directory about some topic named `foo` within which is `foo.xlsx` that I exported from a web site and then `foo.csv` is a sheet a tool I run extracts from it and then `foo.txt` is the output of another tool that provides an analysis of the data contained in that CSV. Or if I run a `graphviz` tool to generate HTML from an input file named `bar` then it'll output `bar.html` and `bar.png`. It's also frequently useful to be able to run `find` to find files with a specific extension. So extensions can be helpful to Unix users.

Comment: @team9 yes, as others said, if you don't show us your file accurately, we can't help you parse it. Please make sure the examples you show are exactly like the real file.

Answer (score 5):

In pure Bash:

```bash
while IFS= read -r line; do
  [[ "$line" =~ /\*.*(pattern_[0-9]+).*\*/ ]] && f="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
  [[ "$line" =~ ^$ ]] || echo "$line" >> "${f}.txt"
  done < file
```

... if you want original blank lines included in the new files, remove `[[ "$line" =~ ^$ ]] ||`.

**Notice** if files named after the pattern names i.e. `pattern_N.txt` pre-exist in the current working directory, then they output will be appended into them which might not be what you want, so clear those files first if the existed before running the above loop.

With AWK (GNU AWK prefered):

```
awk '
/\/\*.*pattern_[0-9]+.*\*\// {
    r = $0
    gsub("[^pattern_0-9]*", "", r)
    out=r".txt"
    print > out
}

! /\/\*.*pattern_[0-9]+.*\*\/|^$/ {
    print > out
}
' file
```

... if you want original blank lines included in the new files, remove `|^$`.

demonstration:

```
$ cat file
/* ----------------- pattern_1 ----------------- */ 

jb: pattern_1   Data: asdflj  adfas Log: dir/log1

/* ----------------- pattern_2 ----------------- */ 

jb: pattern_2   typ: CM comm: ${dir}/DISPV mach: au_buh description: "run flag"


/* ----------------- pattern_3 ----------------- */ 

jb: pattern_3   typ: fw  own: buh out_file: "${log}/jl.log" err: "log.err"
$
$
$ awk '
/\/\*.*pattern_[0-9]+.*\*\// {
    r = $0
    gsub("[^pattern_0-9]*", "", r)
    out=r".txt"
    print > out
}

! /\/\*.*pattern_[0-9]+.*\*\/|^$/ {
    print > out
}
' file
$
$
$ head pattern_*.txt
==> pattern_1.txt <==
/* ----------------- pattern_1 ----------------- */ 
jb: pattern_1   Data: asdflj  adfas Log: dir/log1

==> pattern_2.txt <==
/* ----------------- pattern_2 ----------------- */ 
jb: pattern_2   typ: CM comm: ${dir}/DISPV mach: au_buh description: "run flag"

==> pattern_3.txt <==
/* ----------------- pattern_3 ----------------- */ 
jb: pattern_3   typ: fw  own: buh out_file: "${log}/jl.log" err: "log.err"
```

Comment: Never name a variable `l` as it looks far too much like the number `1` and so obfuscates your code for no benefit.

Comment: @EdMorton It's the habit of choosing variables that relate to their function i.e. `l` for `line` ... But, now, looking at the font used in the code block, I couldn't agree more ... I'll have to find an alternative that relates to `line` and probably use `line` itself in Bash but, then I might get into problems with some AWK builtin functions :D ... Anyway, I shall take that good point into consideration in the future and find something that is safe enough for both (though "old habits die hard" ) ... Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, understood. there's a lot of articles google-able telling us not to use `l` (and a couple of others like `O`). FWIW I'd use `r` for `record` in that context (since awk is record-oriented, lines are just the default) if I felt a burning desire to use a single-char variable, though Id usually just use `rec` or `line`.

Comment: Btw your awk script is doing a couple of things that'll work in GNU awk but YMMV depending on the awk variant you're using, If you care let me know and I'll point them out.

Comment: @EdMorton Sure, please do point them out … Nothing better than knowing more … Thanks!

Comment: 1) `print($0) > l".txt"` is undefined behavior per POSIX. Any awk can read that as `print($0) > (l".txt")` or `(print($0) > l) ".txt"` or anything else and still be POSIX compliant. Many awks will just report it as a syntax error. To be portable you need to put any expression on the right side of output (or input) redirection within parens, i.e. you have to explicitly write `print($0) > (l".txt")`. You never need to write `print($0)`, of course, just `print` does the same thing.

Comment: 2) Every time you create an output file, awk has to open it to write to it. If you create many output files (as few as 10 on some systems, but usually in the thousands) then most awks will fail saying "Too many open files" or similar. GNU awk won't fail, it'll try to manage opening/closing files behind the scenes for you to stay under the system limit but that will greatly slow down processing. It's far better to close output files as you go and so avoid that problem. In this particular case there only ever needs to be 1 output file open at a time so....

Comment: Instead of `l = $0; gsub("[^pattern_0-9]*", "", l); print($0) > l".txt"` you should write `close(out); l = $0; gsub("[^pattern_0-9]*", "", l); out=l".txt"; print($0) > out`. Note that that also solves the problem described in my first point because you no longer have an expression on the right side of the output redirection, you just have a variable that was previously populated from the expression. Your 2nd `print($0) > l".txt"` should then just be `print > out`.

Comment: Since you wanted to hear about issues in your awk script I assume you'd also like to hear about issues with your bash script so... 1) due to the loop it'll be orders of magnitude slower than your awk script no matter what you do to try to improve it. 2) Without `IFS=` before the `read` it'll strip any leading/trailing white space from each line, 3) Doing `while read line; echo "$line" >> foo; done` is much slower than doing `while read line; echo "$line"; done >> foo`. 4) Doing `...done > foo` is usually preferable to `...done >> foo` so the output file gets cleaned out before the loop starts.

Comment: @EdMorton Many thanks! excellent points some of which are an addition to my knowledge and others I already knew but overlooked. That's why I very much appreciate peer review in general and those from an experienced fellow like you in particular ... However, I think the same  `pattern_N` e.g. `pattern_1` might happen in the file many times and not only once like the given example and that's why I opted from using `close()` with `>` in AWK to avoid overwriting the same file again and again loosing previous output as a result ... of course that can be used with `>>` instead but, the results mix..

Comment: ... The same goes for you bash related point re `>` ... although I have initially thought of keeping output in memory e.g. in arrays and write them at once in the end to minimize the frequency of  file writes but again that would be on the expense of system memory which AWK is good at and that's why I included an AWK solution  ... also in Bash `... done >> foo` will require more complex code to handle multiple occurrences of the `pattern_N` ... So, I, reasonably,  preferred compatibility and simplicity over performance ... I think.

Comment: @EdMorton English language discussion: I just realized that `opt from` might actually not be a thing  but rather only [`opt for`](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/opted) ... What I meant above with `opted from` is `didn't choose / steered away from` ... is `opt from` is even correct in that sense? ... Now, I'm afraid this post will be closed as off-topic because of English language discussion :-) (not related to Ubuntu)

Comment: Good point about having multiple output files in the bash script, I forgot that when I was posting my comment. For the awk script, it does get more interesting when you have to reopen the file, I often employ the [Decorate-Sort-Undecorate](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Decorate-sort-undecorate_idiom) idiom when faced with that and close the file when the file name changes so again there's only 1 file open at a time. Yeah, I'm not exactly a native English speaker myself (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scots_language) but I agree that `opted from` isn't correct, it would be `opted not to`.

Comment: FWIW I posted [an answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1501477/1722986) that handles multiple occurrences of a "pattern" and a couple of other rainy day cases not covered by the OPs sample input, feel free to let me know if you see any issues.

Answer (score 3):

With [csplit](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/csplit.1.html) (note, this creates an empty file `pattern_0.txt` that you can suppress by adding the `-z` / `--elide-empty-files` option however that will result in the remaining file numbering being "off" by 1):

```
$ csplit -f 'pattern_' -b '%d.txt' file '/\/\* -\{1,\} pattern_[0-9] -\{1,\} \*\//' '{*}'
0
105
136
129
```

resulting in

```
$ head pattern_{1,2,3}.txt 
==> pattern_1.txt <==
/* ----------------- pattern_1 ----------------- */ 

jb: pattern_1   Data: asdflj  adfas Log: dir/log1


==> pattern_2.txt <==
/* ----------------- pattern_2 ----------------- */ 

jb: pattern_2   typ: CM comm: ${dir}/DISPV mach: au_buh description: "run flag"



==> pattern_3.txt <==
/* ----------------- pattern_3 ----------------- */ 

jb: pattern_3   typ: fw  own: buh out_file: "${log}/jl.log" err: "log.err"
```

The csplit regex can be made simpler depending on your actual use case - for example `'/^\/\*/'` ("line starts with `/*`").

Answer (score 1):

The following accounts for these rainy-day possibilities:

1. The "pattern" between the `---`s may not actually contain the word `pattern`
2. `pattern_<N>` may include `/`s or white space
3. `pattern_<N>` may occur multiple times in the input
4. There may be so many unique `pattern_<N>`s in the input that we would exceed the max number of files a process can have open simultaneously (which would cause most awks to fail with a "Too many open files" error or GNU awk to slow down significantly as it manages opening/closing the files internally as needed).

This input includes the first 3 cases:

```
$ cat file
/* ----------------- pattern_1 ----------------- */

jb: pattern_1   Data: asdflj  adfas Log: dir/log1

/* ----------------- pattern_2 ----------------- */

jb: pattern_2   typ: CM comm: ${dir}/DISPV mach: au_buh description: "run flag"


/* ----------------- blank: tab:        slash: / ----------------- */

jb: pattern_3   typ: fw  own: buh out_file: "${log}/jl.log" err: "log.err"

/* ----------------- pattern_2 ----------------- */

jb: pattern_2   second appearance of pattern_2

/* ----------------- pattern_1 ----------------- */

jb: pattern_1   second appearance of pattern_1
```

and we use the [Decorate-Sort-Undecorate](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Decorate-sort-undecorate_idiom) idiom to group all blocks with the same "pattern" next to each other, but retaining their relative input order, before output file creation so we only need to have 1 output file open at a time to avoid the 4th concern above.

We will map `/` and `\t` from the "pattern" to `_` in the output file names - handle those however you like otherwise if they really can occur.

The following uses GNU awk for the 3rd arg to `match()`, `\s` shorthand for `[[:space:]]`, and to allow use of the NUL char `\0` and GNU sort for `-z`:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

decorate() {
    awk -v OFS='\n' '
        match($0,/^\s*\/\*\s+-+\s+(.*)\s+-+\s+\*\/\s*$/,a) {
            printf "%s%s\t%d\t", blockSep, gensub(/[/\t]/,"_","g",a[1]), NR
            blockSep = "\0"
        }
        { print }
        END { printf "%s", blockSep }
    ' "${@:--}"
}

undecorate() {
    awk -F'\t' -v RS='\n\0' '
        $1 != prev {
            close(out)
            out = $1 ".txt"
            prev = $1
        }
        {
            sub(/^([^\t]+\t){2}/,"")
            print > out
        }
    ' "${@:--}"
}

decorate "${@:--}" |
sort -z -k1,1 -k2,2n |
undecorate
```

```
$ ./tst.sh file
```

```
$ head pattern* blank*
==> pattern_1.txt <==
/* ----------------- pattern_1 ----------------- */

jb: pattern_1   Data: asdflj  adfas Log: dir/log1

/* ----------------- pattern_1 ----------------- */

jb: pattern_1   second appearance of pattern_1


==> pattern_2.txt <==
/* ----------------- pattern_2 ----------------- */

jb: pattern_2   typ: CM comm: ${dir}/DISPV mach: au_buh description: "run flag"


/* ----------------- pattern_2 ----------------- */

jb: pattern_2   second appearance of pattern_2


==> blank: tab:_slash: _.txt <==
/* ----------------- blank: tab:        slash: / ----------------- */

jb: pattern_3   typ: fw  own: buh out_file: "${log}/jl.log" err: "log.err"
```

We could do all of the above in a single call to GNU awk but with the above awk-sort-awk approach awk only has to store 1 "pattern" block of input in memory at a time whereas if we also did the `sort` within gawk then it'd have to hold the whole of the input in memory at once and so YMMV if the input file was massive. By instead using GNU `sort` to handle the sorting, it'll deal with massive files better as it's designed to use demand paging, etc. to handle such input while gawk is not.

Comment: There you go :-) … Demonstrating the "decorate-sort-undecorate" concept is worth it …. Could’ve been earlier … Welcome to AskUbuntu.com and +1 that is earned.